# C: twist char *

Tags: c, arrays, char

Note: I can't use any libs or includes!

I have the following Code:

```
void twstng(char * str, int end, int strt) {
    if(strt != end && strt != end-1) {
            int hlp = str[strt];

            printf("strt %d end %d hlp %d\n", strt, end, hlp);

            str[strt] = str[end-1];

            printf("test\n");

            str[end-1] = hlp;

            printf("test\n");

            twstng(str, strt+1, end-1);
    }
}
```

and in the main function:

```
char * sol = "hello";
twisting(sol, 5, 0);
```

I want to twist the entire string. But the console shows:

```
strt 0 end 4 help 104
```

And then comes a memory access error. But why?

My second problem is, that in the original task the given string is a

```
const char * const str
```

How can I work with it in the twstng function?

Comment: What is this even supposed to do? Reverse the string?

Comment: what does twisting in your context mean?

Comment: You cannot use `printf()` without `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: @pmg Depends on the C standard being used, its implicit type can be correct (in which case you technically can use it without the header, even though you _shouldn't_). Also, we were not shown enough code to know whether the header is included.

Comment: @Arkku: since C89 it's been **UB** to call a function with a variable number of arguments without a prototype in scope (I don't know how calling `printf` before the Standard worked).

Comment: please post the error message!

Comment: @pmg Interesting, as I don't actually have the C89 standard, I've been assuming from the practical behaviour of compilers I've used, and the wording of K&R 2nd ed. ("nothing is assumed about its arguments"), that the implicit type of "takes any arguments, returns `int`" suffices to call `printf`. You may well know better. (Anyhow, I still assume the OPs `printf` calls are for debugging only and not the cause of the error.)

Comment: @Coli As a general comment, I think your variable names are confusing: `strt` seems unnecessarily abbreviated and is very close to `str`, while `end` is apparently not the actual end but "one past the end". You could either do the `- 1` when calling, or call it `length` (or `len` if you must abbreviate).

Comment: The error is an memory access error.
And i can youse printf with int printf(const char * restrict, ...); sry

Comment: @Arkku maybe, but this does not solve the problem

Comment: @Coli I know, that's why I made the observations as a comment. I have also posted an answer about the problem itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `char *sol` is a pointer to the string `"hello"`. Being a string literal, it is actually read-only, and thus when you pass the pointer to your function, you get an error when you modify the contents of the constant string `"hello"` through the pointer.

Regarding the second part of the question, `const char * const` (i.e., constant pointer to a constant `char`) would indeed be a better type for the pointer, as it would convey that the thing pointed to is constant. However, then you cannot pass this pointer to the function (because the function takes a pointer to a non-const `char`), and it is not clear from the information given how you are "allowed" to work around this. One way is to copy the string and modify the copy.

edit: And as pointed out by [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40766223/204883) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40766214/204883), your recursive call mixes up the start and end arguments (by using the more logical order of start first).

Comment: Shouldn't there be a compiler error on assigning `const char*` to `char*`?

Comment: @vlad_tepesch Yes (although it is a warning, not an error), but unfortunately string literals, though read-only, do not have the type `const char *`.

Comment: o_O didn't know this.

Comment: Im compiling with -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror so yes, const char* to char* gives an error. So, how can I copy it in a char and modify it with a void function. Because I can't work with while/for loops.

Comment: @Coli Like said, it is not clear from the information given how you are allowed to fix it in your assignment, and in any case that is probably the part you should learn. That being said, if you can change things at the call site, create an array of `char` long enough for the string and copy the contents there. Don't forget the NUL terminator (`'\0'`) at the end.

Comment: @Coli Why is it `.cpp` (C++) when your code (and the tag of this question) is C? Anyway, an interesting recursive way to implement `strlen` – unfortunately it will probably not work for arbitrarily long strings, but should not be an issue here. Now you just need to copy the string into a new array. You can either make it `static` (e.g., just `static char buf[512]` and you don't support strings longer than 511 characters + terminator), or `malloc(counting(str) + 1)`. Note that `twisting` does not need to return anything, it modifies its argument array.

Answer (score 2):

In C all string literals are *read-only* arrays of characters. It can be stored in memory that is not modifiable, leading to errors such as your when you attempt to modify it. That's why you should always use `const char *` when referring to string literals.

Use an array instead:

```
char sol[] = "hello";
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the recursive call to 'twstng()' at the bottom of the function has passed the new start and end indexes in the wrong order, given the names in the declaration (or else the declaration has them in the wrong order).

Answer (score 2):

You mixed up your arguments.
Your function declaration says, that the first argument is the `end` and the second is the `strt`.

Your recursive call mixes them up.